# Connection pooling service using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java

I created a service for Connection Pooling. And PluginAuth Class will handle those transaction to be send in the server. Is my code structure correct?

```
public class ConnectionPoolingService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConnectionPoolingService.class);

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";

    private static CloseableHttpClient client;
    private static final CookieStore commonCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

    private static final ScheduledExecutorService cleanUpThread = MDScheduledExecutorService.wrap(
            new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1), "connection-pool-cleanup-thread-%d");


    public ConnectionPoolingServiceImpl(String keyStoreId) {
        init(keyStoreId);
    }

    private void init(String keyStoreId) {
        try {
            if (client == null) {
                if (!Util.isNullEmptyOrWhitespace(keyStoreId)) {
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConSocFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(TLSSocketFactoryCache.getInstance().get(keyStoreId),
                            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
                    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                            .register("https", sslConSocFactory).build();

                    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                            .setConnectTimeout(1000)
                            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(1000)
                            .setSocketTimeout(1000)
                            .build();

                    ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrategy = new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
                        public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
                            // Honor 'keep-alive' header
                            HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator(
                                    response.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
                            while (it.hasNext()) {
                                HeaderElement he = it.nextElement();
                                String param = he.getName();
                                String value = he.getValue();
                                if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase("timeout")) {
                                    try {
                                        return Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
                                    } catch(NumberFormatException ignore) {
                                        // ignore
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            try {
                                return 60000;
                            } catch(NumberFormatException ignore) {
                                // ignore
                            }
                            // otherwise keep alive for 60 seconds
                            return 60 * 1000;
                        }
                    };

                    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
                    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(200);
                    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(200);
                    connectionManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(60000);

                    client = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                            .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
                            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                            .setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy)
                            .setConnectionReuseStrategy(new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy())
                            .setUserTokenHandler(context -> null)
                            .setMaxConnTotal(200)
                            .setMaxConnPerRoute(200)
                            .setConnectionTimeToLive(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .build();

                    int closeIdle = 60000;
                    cleanUpThread.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                        try {
                            connectionManager.closeExpiredConnections();
                            connectionManager.closeIdleConnections(closeIdle, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            LOGGER.error("Exception on SGW clean up thread", ex);
                        }
                    }, closeIdle, closeIdle, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                } else {
                    LOGGER.error("Error! No keystore specified, auth param: {}", AuthParamNames.SSL_KEY_TRUST_STORE_ID);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Encountered exception during retrieval of SSL Context", e);
        }
    }

    public Either<String, String> sendRequest(String request, String url) throws IOException {
        String responseString = "";
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(request));
            httpPost.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml");

            HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
            context.setCookieStore(commonCookieStore);

            CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost, context);
            LOGGER.info("Request sent to {}", url);

            int responseStatus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);

            if (HttpStatusCodes.STATUS_CODE_OK == responseStatus) {
                LOGGER.debug("Response received from background auth server.");
                return Either.left(responseString);
            } else {
                return Either.right(String.valueOf(responseStatus));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public static void cleanup() {
        cleanUpThread.shutdownNow();
    }

}


public class PluginAuth {

     private ConnectionPoolingServiceImpl connectionPoolingService;

      public PluginAuth(String keyStoreId) {
          initAuth(keyStoreId);
      }

      private void initAuth(String keyStoreId) {
          connectionPoolingService = new ConnectionPoolingServiceImpl(keyStoreId);
      }

      private String processTransaction(String request, String url) {
          String responseString = "";
        try {
            Either<String, String> result = connectionPoolingService.sendRequest(request, url);


            if (result.isLeft()) {
                responseString = result.left().value();
                LOGGER.debug("Response received from server.");
            } else if (result.isRight()) {
                //throw exeception?
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return responseString;
      }

}
```